# Stage or studio furniture

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, slang

Is there a collective name for the table/bench/chair configuration used by contestants on such as family TV game shows?

Comment: On Stargate Atlantis they used common IKEA stuff to furnish Atlantis :D

Answer (score 4):

**Prop** or **Theatrical Property** - [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatrical_property).

> A prop is considered to be anything movable or portable on a stage or a set, distinct from the actors, scenery, costumes, and electrical equipment.

Eg: The only *props* used in the show are a table, a chair, and a glass of water. [**Cambridge Dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/prop)

Comment: Also, most incidental or decorative items fall into the category of ***set dressing***

Answer (score 1):

The only game show I can clearly visualize in my mind is Jeopardy.  There the contestants each have sort of a *lectern*.  They stand side by side.  Maybe we could call it a triple-lectern.

If you could supply an image or a sketch it would be helpful.

Comment: I think lectern is an appropriate term. I while it might not exist in a dictionary, doing a Google search for the terms "game show lectern" and "game show podium" provide results.